# Push down DML commands to SQL using Pyspark on Databricks

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure's Databricks and want to pushdown a query to a Azure SQL using PySpark. I've tried many ways and found a solution using Scala (code below), but doing this I need to convert part of my code to scala then bring back to PySpark again.

```
%scala
import java.util.Properties
import java.sql.DriverManager

val jdbcUsername = username
val jdbcPassword = password
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
val jdbcUrl = "entire-string-connection-to-Azure-SQL"

// Create a Properties() object to hold the parameters.
val connectionProperties = new Properties()

connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
val stmt = connection.createStatement()
val sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table"

stmt.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```

Is there a way to achieve the pushdown of a DML code using PySpark instead of Scala language?

Found something related but only works to read data and DDL commands:

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword,
  "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
}

pushdown_query = "(select * from employees where emp_no < 10008) emp_alias"
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Comment: have you read this blog https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Comment: @MaheshGupta, thanks for replying. Yes, that's where I got from the second part [link](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#id1). But as said, only shows example reading from JDBC connector, unfortunatelly it doesn't show how to pushdown.

Comment: After creating statment you can same as scala does

Comment: After reading carefully the Spark documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html found out some clue to implement the truncate cmd:

    df.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table="TABLE", mode="overwrite", properties=connectionProperties)

It doesn't implement a general query push down like done by Scala but already solves the truncate issue.

Comment: @MaheshGupta, the blog doesn't show how to do this, anyway, Could you please exemplify what you mean by 'you can same as scala does' in a cleaner way? Because in the example Scala uses the DriverManager from java.
Additionally, in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443857/delete-azure-sql-database-rows-from-azure-databricks?rq=1 the approach is the same (converting to to Scala), so, doesn't seems to be so simple like you said, if so, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve the same thing as the Scala example you provided in Python.

```
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
connection = driver_manager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
query = "YOUR SQL QUERY"
exec_statement = connection.prepareCall(query)
exec_statement.execute()
exec_statement.close()
connection.close()
```

For your case I would try

```
driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
connection = driver_manager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
stmt = connection.createStatement()
sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.table"
stmt.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```