# Connect Azure SQL server using Pyspark

Tags: python, azure, pymssql

I have a huge dataset in SQL server, I want to Connect the SQL server with python, then use pyspark to run the query. When I am trying to connect gives error.
below code is not working:

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect("MFCGaZURESERVERHOST.database.windows.net", "Mfc\SVC_Account", "rYa9NqsUpuN2kCm", "jp-database_Name")

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("DELETE from SELECTIONTAIL where 1=1")
conn.commit()
```

Comment: You are not using pyspark anywhere in this piece of code. However you can refer to this answer as it is similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54443857/delete-azure-sql-database-rows-from-azure-databricks. It uses pyodbc

Comment: Could you please provide whole code and error?

Comment: @Bhavani: 
pyspark code 

:readDBTable = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mftsqldbuteee01.database.windows.net:1433;database=jp-ab-db;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=mfcghghdbutydevjpe01.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=20;").option("dbtable", "PGI_data").option("user", "MEEGD\SVC_EBK_AL_JP_DEV").option("password", "rYa9NqsUpuN2kCm").load() 

Error :
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'MEEGD\SVC_EBK_AL_JP_DEV'. ClientConnectionId:f8029f7c-0e28-4308-b6c9-d08ca1147c10

Answer (score 0):

As @Anupam Chand said you can use `pyodbc`  package to connect azure SQL database and execute quires in azure SQL database. You can run below code to execute delete query:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'                       'SERVER=<serverName>.database.windows.net;'
                      'DATABASE=<dbName>;'
                      'UID=<userName>;'
                      'PWD= <pasword>')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('DELETE FROM student WHERE 1 = 1')
conn.commit()
rows_affected = cursor.rowcount
print(f'Rows affected: {rows_affected}')
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

You can get number of rows deleted as output for above code as mentioned below:

[image]

Comment: Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Comment: Install odbc driver in your environment

Comment: pyspark code 

:readDBTable = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mftsqldbuteee01.database.windows.net:1433;database=jp-ab-db;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=mfcghghdbutydevjpe01.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=20;").option("dbtable", "PGI_data").option("user", "MEEGD\SVC_EBK_AL_JP_DEV").option("password", "rYa9NqsUpuN2kCm").load() 

Error :
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'MEEGD\SVC_EBK_AL_JP_DEV'. ClientConnectionId:f8029f7c-0e28-4308-b6c9-d08ca1147c10

Comment: Client don't want to use ODBC, They wants to connect using JDBC

Comment: Could you please provide where you are executing the code?